# Rails - A table for every single ID or a everything is a single table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-design, model

I'm fairly new to rails - web development in general and I'm not sure how to implement the following

> I have a large list of books, each book has a specific book_ID and for every book_ID, I have x copies of that book each with details unique to them.

What I'm thinking is that I should have a main table that has the details of that specific book and from this main table, I'll refer to a table for each specific book_ID.

Example

> book - "10, Apple's bees", "20 Funny Bees" ......
>
> 10 - book 1, book 2, book 3, .... #book x refers to a sepcific book with book_id 10.

Does this sound like the right way to do it? If so, how do I accomplish this in rails? How do I automatically create an arbitrary number of tables that uses book_ID as the table name?

Comment: I think you need to take a step back from rails and look at basic programming terms. What do you mean by "multiple different of book" and "multiples of each book"

Comment: @AbePetrillo Care to elaborate on that? Basically I have a list of books and there are x number of every single book (they have a slight difference and I need each and every record of it, eg. special ID numbers)

Comment: Take a look at my answer and see if it helps you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm translating `book_id` can be renamed to `reference number`. At a very basic level, I'd do

Use the scaffolding to create a class of Book (along with a controller and views)

`rails generate scaffold Book name:string title:string reference_no:integer`

You can now add your books such as the first one, a new book with a title of "Apple's bees" and a reference number of 10.

Id then create another seperate class called Copy, and you can use a `has_many` relationship to Books

```
class Copy
  belongs_to :books
end
```

and in your Book class:

```
class Book
  has_many :copies
end
```

In terms of how this looks in the database, you will have two tables: books and copies.

Each record in the copies table will have a `reference` to the book it belongs to.

Comment: I get this idea and it would work perfectly fine if I had <100 books. What if I had 1000 books and there are 500 copies of each? It'll probably take a long time to retrieve all 500 copies of book_id 1 (especially if they are not inserted in order to the copies table). If I were to have a single table for book_id 1, I could just return everything from that single table instead.

Comment: Listen to @abe he speaks the truth :) -- but seriously, what is the actual problem you are trying to solve? If you're just playing around, I highly recommend this tutorial, it's free, and a great way to get started with Rails and the modern web development workflow: http://ruby.railstutorial.org/

Comment: It's not that @abe's method doesn't work. It works just fine (as I've stated in the previous comment) but I'm just trying to solve the problem in an more efficient manner. Having to call the database a thousand times with a query like that will turn out very badly in my opinion.

Comment: Who said you had to call the database 100 times? Again it depends on your specific problem. You can get any combination you need with one SQL query if that's what your bothered about.

Comment: Yes, I can get all the entries with 1 single query but what if I have a thousand users trying to execute that query? I'm thinking of scalability issues.

Comment: Worry about scalability when it becomes a problem. This scales much better than having one big table

Comment: I'll accept this answer based on "worry about scalability when it becomes a problem". Thanks!